# Editing Individual Tiles From ArcGIS Online Tiled Map Service

Tags: arcgis-online, tiles, tile-server

Is there a way to edit or replace tiles individually?

For example, if I have published a tiled layer and need to update small details of that layer I currently have to overwrite the entire tiled layer resulting in a large use of credits for a small change.

By accessing the Admin section of the tile layer, the following supported operations are available:

- Edit
- Refresh
- Swap
- Cancel
- UpdateTiles
- ImportTiles
- DeleteTiles

I am not sure if any of these operations would help in achieving what I am trying to do, or if there is another workflow or tool that may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, the answer is no. When you publish data or maps as a hosted web layer in AGOL the tile layers are predawn map images, which means (I am pretty sure) that AGOL expects you have authored the map as you want it displayed before you share the hosted layer out as a tile package. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to replace a single tile with an updated tile containing altered display information (at the same extent), to circumvent a full re-publishing of the service because I was initially concerned about credit usage.

However, it appears as though a re-published of the tiled layer did not use as many credits as I thought it might.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can update just 1 tile. To avoid burning AGOL credits, you can generate the tiles in ArcGIS desktop using the 'Create Map Tile Package' tool and then share them to AGOL with the 'Share Package' tool.